# what is the difference between _EPROCESS object and _KPROCESS object

Tags: windows, kernel

Upon analysis, I learnt that even _KPROCESS objects can be members of the ActiveProcessLinks list. What is the difference between _EPROCESS and _KPROCESS objects? When is one created and one not? What are the conceptual differences between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Arun-Kishan-Process-Management-in-Windows-Vista

`EPROCESS` is the kernel mode equivalent of the `PEB` from user mode. More details can be found in [this document](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/part1.pdf) on Alex Ionescu's site as well as [the book by Schreiber](http://undocumented.rawol.com/) and other books about the NT internals.

Use `dt` in WinDbg to get an idea how they look.

Answer (score 11):

This is simplified, but the kernel mode portion of the Windows O/S is broken up into three pieces: the HAL, the Kernel, and the Executive Subsystems. The Executive Subsystems deal with general O/S policy and operation. The Kernel deals with process architecture specific details for low level operations (e.g. spinlocks, thread switching) as well as scheduling. The HAL deals with differences that arise in particular implementations of a processor architecture (e.g. how interrupts are routed on this implementation of the x86). This is all explained in greater detail in the Windows Internals book.

When you create a new Win32 process, both the Kernel and the Executive Subsystems want to track it. For example, the Kernel wants to know the priority and affinity of the threads in the process because that's going to affect scheduling. The Executive Subsystems want to track the process because, for example, the Security Executive Subsystem wants to associate a token with the process so we can do security checking later.

The structure that the Kernel uses to track the process is the KPROCESS. The structure that the Executive Subsystems use to track it is the EPROCESS. As an implementation detail, the KPROCESS is the first field of the EPROCESS, so the Executive Subsystems allocate the EPROCESS structure and then call the Kernel to initialize the KPROCESS portion of it. In the end, both structures are part of the Process Object that represents the instance of the user process. This should also all be covered in the Windows Internals book.

-scott

Answer (score 2):

EPROCESS is not available in user mode. Neither is KPROCESS.

KPROCESS is a subset of EPROCESS. If you look at the fields in a debugger, you'll see the KPROCESS contains fields more related to scheduling and book-keeping of the process at a lower level, while EPROCESS has higher-level process contexts inside of it. The names, as far as I am aware, come from different subsystems that interact with these structures (the Executive has structures and functions frequently prefixed with Ex while the Kernel has structures and functions frequently prefixed with Ke)

You can see this in different documented functions. Consider the prototype for KeStackAttachProcess ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549659(v=vs.85).aspx ), which is a Ke functions and takes a KPROCESS. There aren't any exported and documented Ex functions that accept EPROCESS (or KPROCESS), but Ps functions deal entirely in EPROCESSES.

A similar divide exists for threads, with KTHREAD and ETHREAD.